# How to fit map to show all markers from json array on the map

Tags: android, google-maps

I have cordinates from json and I want to show them all in map , here it shows markers but some of them not appear I want to set zoom to fit appearing all markers in map ,how can I do it ?

```
     JSONArray postsJson = success.getJSONArray("now");
                        for (int i = 0; i < postsJson.length(); i++) {
  Order_Start_Lat=c.getDouble("order_start_latitude");
                                   Order_Start_Lng=c.getDouble("order_start_longitude");


                            MarkerOptions m = new MarkerOptions()
                                    .title(client_name)
                                    .position(new LatLng(Order_Start_Lat,Order_Start_Lng));
                            map.addMarker(m);
                            LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
                            builder.include(new LatLng(Order_Start_Lat,Order_Start_Lng));
                            LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
                            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20));
```

Comment: I suggest you find the distance between furthest markers and based on that set the zoom

Comment: I don't think so , it must be a simple way in android to do it

Comment: there isn't any method for that purpose

Comment: Just add all your `LatLng` to your `LatLngBounds`

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `CameraUpdate` class to do (probably) all programmatic map movements.

To do this, first calculate the bounds of all the markers like so:

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
for (Marker marker : markers) {
    builder.include(marker.getPosition());
}
LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
```

Then obtain a movement description object by using the factory: CameraUpdateFactory:

```
int padding = 0; // offset from edges of the map in pixels
CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
```

Finally move the map:

```
googleMap.moveCamera(cu);
```

Comment: I got "java.lang.illegalstateexception no included points"
in this line "  LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();"